# Read mail-address from "To"-Field on a reply

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing a VSTO-Addin in Outlook. 
When replying to an e-mail a new Outlook.MailItem ist created. In this Object I have the "To" attribute.

In outlook it shows something like:

> Gregory Porter <gregory.porter@google.de>

When I read myMailItem.To I only get:

> Gregory Porter

But I do need the E-Mail-Adress. How can I read this? Maybe there is a way to read the suggested contacts? But I don't know how to access them via VSTO.

Comment: How about `Recipients` instead of `To`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection and for each Recipient object check that its Type property == olTo. You can then read the Recipient.Address property.

Comment: Oh damn. I didn't see this property yesterday. Maybe it was too late. I will check it and keep you up to date.

Comment: Working as expected! Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you are processing EX type (as opposed to SMTP) addresses correctly - read the PR_ADDRTYPE property using Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty. If it is "EX", use Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress

Comment: Can you please explain why I have to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because for the Exchange recipients, Recipient.Address will be something like "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=2d848b4d77d047e782eea3713d9c1b8e-dmitry_0502"